# libgdx touchup using gesturelistener

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, gesturelistener

What is the best/easiest way to detect "TouchUp" using the GestureListener in libgdx. (In previous projects I used InputListener and this had TouchUp but no pan or fling).

All I need to do right now is set my MovingLeft or MovingRight booleans to False once the finger is lifted.

```
package com.moneylife.stashinvaders;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Player {
    Vector2 position;
    Texture texture;
    int speed = 500;
    float deltaTime;
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    boolean MovingRight = false, MovingLeft = false;


    public Player(int ScreenW, int ScreenH){
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector()));
        texture = new Texture("bazookaman.png");
        position = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth() / 2 - texture.getWidth() / 2, 0);
        screenWidth = ScreenW;
        screenHeight = ScreenH;
    }

    public void update(){
        deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (MovingRight){
            position.x += speed * deltaTime;
        }
        if (MovingLeft){
            position.x -= speed * deltaTime;
        }
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
        spriteBatch.draw(texture, position.x, position.y);
    }


    public class MyGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.GestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if (x > position.x) {
                MovingRight = true;
            }
            if (x < position.x){
                MovingLeft = true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            MovingLeft = false;
            MovingRight = false;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void pinchStop() {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a much simpler way for my basic needs in this project. It's called polling rather than using GestureListener (or inputprocessor) at all:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            if (Gdx.input.getX() > position.x) {
                position.x += speed * deltaTime;
            }
            if (Gdx.input.getX() < position.x) {
                position.x -= speed * deltaTime;
            }
        }
```

Works and player movement is seemless (excluding if the finger goes too near player, but i'm only experimenting here so not worried about that)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `GestureDetector` and `InputProcessor` interfaces and put them in a `InputMultiplexer` which is being inserted into `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor`.

Comment: Hi thanks. I did see about these but wasn't sure if that was necessary simply to get the touchup. From what you're telling me this is the best option so I will research into this now. thanks again

Comment: @Ronny I have no clue why these gestures are not combined in a single Interface but it really doesn't matter, you just have a couple of extra empty implementation methods in your code.

Comment: I was actually looking for Gdx.input.isTouched() which someone kindly reminded me of in IRC. Then using the getX() and getY() methods polling for input is definitely simpler in my situation here. I can now delete the entire GestureListener code as it's not needed in this project. Just thought Id add this in case anyone suffering similar headaches reads this

Comment: @Ronny If you are really sure it's all you need in your project then that is fine. But the interfaces are much more "extendable" and keep your code nice and clean. You can also override the interactions where as with your method it just always detects the touch. I only use your technique for some quick fiddling around when my final class does not need input at all.

Comment: Thanks again for all your advice. At this stage I am just learning very basics of how to put things together and so the simple approach was ok for my example. Sadly i did give up on this project for now and now I am looking at scaling maps with the camera class and adding TMX files etc... fun awaits :D

Comment: Scaling with the camera is easy `camera.zoom = .5f` makes everything double as large. If you are using the camera's `.unproject(..)` for all interactions with your map everything will be functioning properly.

Comment: thanx dude. when i say scaling I'm actually meaning to say 2d game dev where the sprites scale per device resolution etc correctly and the game logic being in units rather than pixels etc.... like i said I'm very much a novice beginner here even though I've been attempting to learn coding over several years with many languages I never quite mastered any. With the excepttion of XNA where I could at least make some complete games for PC that where ok fun haha.

Comment: Just use `Viewport` to handle different sizes. You have `viewports` that stretch the camera's view to the screen so larger devices see more, `viewports` that stretch the gameworld to the screen so sprites might get out of aspect, `viewports` that add bars to maintain aspect ratio, and a couple more.

Java isn't much different then `C#`, `LibGDX` documentation is currently very complete so the step between `XNA` and `LibGDX` is very small.

Comment: If you could be so kind, please look at this question i put up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935310/libgdx-camera-setting-position-having-no-effect     It should be easy for you I reckon but cant figure out why it wont move